# Invalid literal for int() with base 10: '63,'

Tags: python

I am running the following program and it produces the following failure. I think the logic is right. What is wrong?

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: '63,'
```

Code:

```
for i in range(length):
    k=i+1
    if (sample_text[i]  == "r" and sample_text[k] == "e" ):
        iTemp = i
        iTemp = iTemp + 9 
        var = ""
        finalList = []
        while (sample_text[iTemp] != "]"):
            iTemp = iTemp + 1 
            while (sample_text[iTemp] != "," or sample_text[iTemp] != "]"):
                tempVar = sample_text[iTemp]
                var = var + tempVar
                num = int(var)
                iTemp = iTemp + 1
```

Comment: You are trying to convert a string which contains a comma to an integer. What's not clear about the error message?

Answer (score 2):

Lets say that `sample_text[iTemp]` is equal to `","`. then the expression

```
sample_text[iTemp] != "," or sample_text[iTemp] != "]"
```

will be equal to `False or True`, which is equal to `True` and you enter the loop body and append the comma to the text.

The logical operator you want here is `and`:

```
sample_text[iTemp] != "," and sample_text[iTemp] != "]"
```